# Adding a system dependency to an existing app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I need `pymssql` which in turn needs `freetds-dev` available on the system. My app has been running on the Heroku Cedar stack for a few years. I haven't used a custom buildpack, but looks like the only way to add this functionality is with a custom buildpack. All the examples mostly talk about creating new apps with a buildpack. What happens when I already have an app running that I do not want to break but add a new system dependency?